# Maven: How to configure native2ascii-maven-plugin

Tags: java, maven

Im firing this question at you guys since the project-page itself has not a lot of information.
Basicly im setting up the native2ascii-maven-plugin to process some of my resources. It works fine for processing the files in root directory. But now i have files under subdirectory: `/template/email/` and would like them to be included in the processing. Can you guys please help me out?

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>native2ascii-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-alpha-1</version>
        <configuration>
            <dest>target/resources</dest>
            <src>src/main/resources</src>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>native2ascii-utf8</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>native2ascii</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF8</encoding>
                    <includes>ApplicationResources*.properties, errors.properties, /template/email/newBooking*.ftl</includes>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Thanks a bunch!!

Comment: Do you mean by root directory outside the scope of the current maven project?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to define a execution section for every folder you want to process and move the src and dest to the execution part:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>native2ascii-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-alpha-1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>native2ascii-utf8-resources</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>native2ascii</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <dest>target/resources</dest>
                <src>src/main/resources</src>
                <encoding>UTF8</encoding>
                <includes>ApplicationResources*.properties, errors.properties, /template/email/newBooking*.ftl</includes>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>native2ascii-utf8-email</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>native2ascii</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <dest>target/resources/email</dest>
                <src>src/main/templates/email</src>
                <encoding>UTF8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that native2ascii [doesn't support `dest/src`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/native2ascii-maven-plugin/native2ascii-mojo.html).

Comment: 1.0-alpha-1 supports dest/src. But 1.0-beta-1 defines new <workDir> as src and dest, which means 1.0-beta-1 output will overwrite our input, which is wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Here a solution for "native2ascii". All files (recursively) found in `src/main/locale` are destined to `target/classes`:

```
<project>
    [...]
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>native2ascii-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-alpha-1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>native2ascii</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <encoding>UTF8</encoding>
                            <src>src/main/locale</src>
                            <dest>target/classes</dest>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            [...]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample configuration for version 1.0-beta-1:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>native2ascii-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-beta-1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>native2ascii-utf8-resources</id>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>native2ascii</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <workDir>src/main/resources</workDir>
                        <encoding>UTF8</encoding>
                        <tempDir>${basedir}/temp</tempDir>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*_fa.properties</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

In case of error, you can check the plugin source code [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.codehaus.mojo/native2ascii-maven-plugin/1.0-beta-1/org/codehaus/mojo/native2ascii/Native2AsciiMojo.java?av=f).

Comment: I was migrating from Java6 to Java8, hence I was required to upgrade 1.0-alpha-1 to 1.0-beta-1. 1.0-beta-1 has 2 problems (1) the pom xml syntax has changed, no more src and dest. (2) the new workDir acts as the src and dest folder, which is wrong, because the output will overwrite the original input source file.

Comment: https://davidsimpson.me/2015/03/04/automated-native2ascii-character-conversion-internationalization-atlassian-add-ons/ suggests 1.0-alpha-1 can be reused with dependency on Jdk6- tools.jar.

Comment: I am using the `1.0-beta-1` version with `src`/`dest` parameters. The IntelliJ Idea complains about it but it seems to work for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36573916/how-to-get-rid-of-maven-plugin-configuration-error-in-intellij-idea

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample configuration for version 2.0+

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>native2ascii-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>native2ascii-utf8-properties</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase> 
            <goals>
                <goal>inplace</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <dir>${project.build.directory}/classes</dir>
                <includes>**/*.properties</includes>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Worked for me after changing <dir>${project.build.directory}/classes</dir> to <dir>${project.build.directory}</dir>, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have recently created another version of native2ascii maven plugin, that covers usage of both old versions and also contains XML files used by m2e Eclipse plugin: https://github.com/dmatej/native2ascii/releases

I have to force someone to put it to official maven repositories ... but you can still use it in your own.

Answer (score 0):

The drawback in 1.0-beta-1 is the approach with **workDir**.
I don't wanna change my source code in each build, but I still need some tool to provide unicode anotation to my property files.

So I've solved the issue with two configuration:

1. Set workDir to your project's target;
2. Change the phase to something after process-resources;

   ```
   <plugin>
     <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
     <artifactId>native2ascii-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>1.0-beta-1</version>
     <executions>
       <execution>
         <id>native2ascii-utf8-i18n</id>
         <phase>compile</phase>
         <goals>
           <goal>native2ascii</goal>
         </goals>
         <configuration>
           <workDir>target/classes/i18n</workDir>
           <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
           <includes>
             <include>**/*.properties</include>
           </includes>
         </configuration>
       </execution>
     </executions>
   </plugin>
   ```

I've used phase 'compile' since inside IDE is the one I use most.