# How to get rid of maven plugin configuration error in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I have this red color for `<src />` and `<dest />` in **IntelliJ Idea**. Is it possible to fix the `pom.xml` parsing error?

Prefferred way is to not disable the checks.

Edited:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>native2ascii-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>native2ascii-utf8-resources</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>native2ascii</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <src>src/main/resources</src>
                <encoding>UTF8</encoding>
                <dest>target/classes</dest>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

IntelliJ Idea Screenshot so it is clear what I mean:

[image]

Also the project module seems to have an error:

[image]

Comment: 1. Screenshot = insta-downvote. 2. Maybe because it's normal, `src` isn't a configuration element for this plugin?

Comment: What is wrong with the screenshot? I would like to get rid of the error, ever since I open the pom.xml then I see project errors in `Project` view. src is valid configuration element of the plugin.

Comment: You shouldn't post a screenshot of your code but directly your code.

Comment: The screenshot was intention so it is clearly visible what I am asking for. If I post code, it would be less obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ highliths as red not valid elements (based on plugin XSDs).

Support of *src* and *dest* tags for native2ascii-maven-plugin varies among versions. (1.0-beta-1 and 1.0-alpha-1 atm).

Check the docs of your precise version.

Give a look at: [Maven: How to configure native2ascii-maven-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105039/maven-how-to-configure-native2ascii-maven-plugin)

Comment: I am using `1.0-beta-1` version. Finally I see that if I unpack the `native2ascii-maven-plugin-1.0-beta-1.jar` there is `plugin.xml` file that defines the parameters. It seems this version supports the `src`/`dest` parameters but these are not documented in `plugin.xml` and this causes the pom.xml error. `workDir` should be used instead.